# include-what-you-use with cmake: path to exucutable of iwyu

Tags: cmake, include-what-you-use

In installed the tool "include-what-you-use", see [here](https://include-what-you-use.org/).

I use cmake and with the option

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE = /path/to/iwyu_executable ..
```

Once I downloaded include-what-you-use from the link above, I can not find any executable in the folder. So what is /path/to/iwyu_executable supposed to be?